# forcing argument and return type restrictions on a function based on it's parameterized types

Tags: scala

I'm learning my way through Scala object and type system and as an exercise I decided to implement a Saiyan training application where a Saiyan can train other Saiyans to level up.

```
    class Saiyan
    class SuperSaiyan extends Saiyan
    class SuperSaiyan2 extends SuperSaiyan
    class SuperSaiyan3 extends SuperSaiyan2

    trait Trainer[A <: Saiyan]{
      def train(trainee: A):A
    }

    val noob = new Saiyan
    val goku = new SuperSaiyan2 with Trainer[SuperSaiyan2] {
        //needs override define of train method.
    }

    val trainedNoob = goku.train(noob)
```

the `Trait Trainer` impelimentation is superficial. I want some restrictions on the train method as listed below:

1. the `SuperSaiyan2`'s train method can accept instances of `Saiyan`,
   `SuperSaiyan` and `SuperSaiyan2` **but not** `SuperSaiyan3`.
2. `SuperSaiyan2` cannot train a trainee to become `SuperSaiyan3`.
3. Whatever trainee the `SuperSaiyan2` takes cannot level down. it must always either level up or stay the same.

If possible how can I implement this in this snippet of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Disclaimer: This problem is unsolvable in the given terms.

Specifically you can not logically satisfy this requirements

1. any `SuperSaiyan2` instance can train nothing above `SuperSaiyan2`
2. `SuperSaiyan3` instance can train `SuperSayian3`
3. `SuperSaiyan3` is a subtype of `SuperSaiyan2`

As you can see due to `3.`, a `Supersayan3` instance is also a `SuperSaiyan2` instance, therefore `1.` and `2.` makes a contradiction

But you can try to set some bounds, making them abstract on type level, but specified on instance level

### UPDATE:

#### Hierarchy semi-solution

The most simple approach that could compile with given terms and example would be

```
class Saiyan {
  type Level <: Saiyan
  def train[T <: Saiyan](trainee: T)(implicit ev: Level <:< trainee.Level): Saiyan = Saiyan()
}

object Saiyan {
  def apply() = new Saiyan {type Level = Saiyan}
}

class SuperSaiyan extends Saiyan {
  type Level <: SuperSaiyan
  override def train[T <: Saiyan](trainee: T)(implicit ev: Level <:< trainee.Level): SuperSaiyan = SuperSaiyan()
}

object SuperSaiyan {
  def apply() = new SuperSaiyan {type Level = SuperSaiyan}
}

class SuperSaiyan2 extends SuperSaiyan {
  type Level <: SuperSaiyan
  override def train[T <: Saiyan](trainee: T)(implicit ev: Level <:< trainee.Level): SuperSaiyan2 = SuperSaiyan2()
}

object SuperSaiyan2 {
  def apply() = new SuperSaiyan2 {type Level = SuperSaiyan2}
}

class SuperSaiyan3 extends SuperSaiyan2 {
  type Level <: SuperSaiyan3
  override def train[T <: Saiyan](trainee: T)(implicit ev: Level <:< trainee.Level): SuperSaiyan3 = SuperSaiyan3()
}

object SuperSaiyan3 {
  def apply() = new SuperSaiyan3 {type Level = SuperSaiyan3}
}
  override def train[T <: Saiyan](trainee: T)(implicit ev: UpperBound <:< trainee.UpperBound): SuperSaiyan3 = SuperSaiyan3()
}

object SuperSaiyan3 {
  def apply() = new SuperSaiyan3 {type UpperBound = SuperSaiyan3}
}
```

this code will succesfully compile code like

```
val goku = SuperSaiyan2()

goku.train(Saiyan())
```

but further

```
goku.train(goku.train(Saiyan()))
```

will fail, because info about `type Level` was lost after `train`ing. Making this type available after any count of `train`ing in my best approach leads to cyclic type references, which is illegal in the current scala.

#### Typeclass

So if you really want type-level hierarchy with partial order, you can introduce some typeclass for that

```
class CanTrain[+A, B]
trait SelfCanTrain[T] {
  implicit val canTrainSelf: CanTrain[T, T] = new CanTrain
}

class Saiyan {
  def train[T](trainee: T)(implicit ev: CanTrain[T, Saiyan]) = new Saiyan
}

object Saiyan extends SelfCanTrain[Saiyan]

class SuperSaiyan extends Saiyan {
  def train[T](trainee: T)(implicit ev: CanTrain[T, SuperSaiyan]) = new SuperSaiyan
}

object SuperSaiyan extends SelfCanTrain[SuperSaiyan] 

class SuperSaiyan2 extends SuperSaiyan {
  def train[T](trainee: T)(implicit ev: CanTrain[T, SuperSaiyan2])= new SuperSaiyan2
}

object SuperSaiyan2 extends SelfCanTrain[SuperSaiyan2]

class SuperSaiyan3 extends SuperSaiyan2 {
  def train[T](trainee: T)(implicit ev: CanTrain[T, SuperSaiyan3])= new SuperSaiyan3
}

object SuperSaiyan3 extends SelfCanTrain[SuperSaiyan3]
```

From now on very transitive

```
goku.train(goku.train(goku.train(new Saiyan)))
```

would be succesfully compiled

Comment: Thank you but I pasted ur code on ide. `goku.train([any instance of Saiyan hierarchy here])` doesn't compile.

Comment: @shayan Could you please specify scala version you use. I'm pretty sure it should compile as it is in 2.11.8 - 2.12.1

Comment: right now I'm on 2.12.1 and the error i get for any `.train(new Saiyan)`  run is this: `Error:(54, 13) type mismatch;
 found   : A$A270.this.Saiyan
 required: T
goku.train(new Saiyan)
           ^`

Comment: The T type should be infered right? as I'm passing it in inside the argument anyway

Comment: @shayan Yes, my asnwer has flaws, I'll try to improve it little bit later

Comment: brilliant! the last solution involving Implicit Evidence (if  I'm not mistaken) seems right on spot. this looks like it cannot get any shorter than that as this  technique is used inside the core library as well apparently. (according to this book I'm reading atm :"Programming Scala" by Dean Wampler & Alex Payne) . ty brilliant! brilliant! brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

`trait Trainer[A <: Saiyan]{
  def train[B >: A, C >:A <:B](trainee: B) : C
}`

Thus the train method takes two additional type parameters:

- B which must be a super type of A. `B >: A` (**Solves 1.**)
- C which must also be a super type of A. `C >: A` (**Solves 3.**) but also a sub-type of B `.. <: B` (**Solves 2.**)

  **EDIT:** Solution is mistaken; See Odomontois's answer as to why.

Comment: thank you. when I saw ur answer I was hoping this would be what I was looking for.  the return type of implementation is within correct Lower bound. but sadly `(new SuperSaiyan2).train` method can both accept `SuperSaiyan3` and return `SuperSaiyan3`. none of which is acceptable. any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I just saw Odomontois's answer and was about to edit mine.

What he says is correct about it being impossible within the given parameters. I'll try to think of something

Answer (score 0):

Tried using shapeless Nat to restrict compilation based on the level of a Saiyan

```
import shapeless.Nat
import shapeless.nat._
import shapeless.ops.nat._

trait Saiyan[A <: Nat] {
   def train[B <: Nat, C <: Nat](b: Saiyan[B])(implicit blt: B LT A): Saiyan[C] =
     ???
}

class SuperSaiyan extends Saiyan[_1]
class SuperSaiyan2 extends Saiyan[_2]
class SuperSaiyan3 extends Saiyan[_3]


val noob = new Saiyan[_0] {}
val goku = new SuperSaiyan2
```

Now the line `goku.train(noob)` compiles, but `noob.train(goku)` does not.

Comment: I'd like to +1 this question, but really can't, because I feel author was asking about modelling hierarchy without order, only with partial order.